# Swagger authorize anonymous requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a minimal api. I've set up JWT bearer authentication in the api and added Swagger docs.

There are different endpoint groups in my api: some of them require authorization and some of them can work if user is both authorized and if he is not unathorized. The logic of work differs in both cases but it doesn't relate to the question.

Endpoints with required authorization are mapped with the following code:

```
var group = app.MapGroup("api/group1").WithTags("tag1").RequireAuthorization();
//mapping group endpoints
```

and it works perfectly fine. I can set `Bearer` token in Swagger UI and execute the request. I can see that Swagger fills `Authorization: Bearer` header with the provided token.

Next, if I need to allow both anonymous and authorized access to my endpoints group, I need to use both `RequireAuthorization` and `AllowAnonymous`, right? So I've tried this:

```
var group = app.MapGroup("api/group2").WithTags("tag2").RequireAuthorization().AllowAnonymous();
//mapping group endpoints
```

In this case, when I try to execute the request in Swagger, the authorization middleware is completely passed (even if toke is provided in Swagger UI) and the user is not authorized. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have auth and anonymous at the same time, that makes no sense. They are opposites of each other.

Comment: If you want to read something from the token ignoring if its used for authorization or not then write a middleware that just does that and is not the or a authorization middleware.

Comment: @DavidG but if I call this endpoint from postman or curl or smth and add `Authentication` header manually everything works fine... The only problem is that swagger doesn't add this header to request with `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

Comment: Btw it is said [in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-8.0) that when using both `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous`:
`Authentication middleware is not short-circuited but doesn't need to succeed.`

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to execute the request in Swagger, the authorization
> middleware is completely passed (even if toke is provided in Swagger
> UI) and the user is not authorized.

Well, according to your scenario, description and along with the shared code snippet, its obvious that,  combining `RequireAuthorization` and `AllowAnonymous` together shouldn't work and  isn't recommended for mixed access groups.

Instead, consider separating authorized/anonymous endpoints, creating custom middleware for conditional authorization, or using alternative security schemes in Swagger (if applicable).

> What am I doing wrong?

The reason `.RequireAuthorization().AllowAnonymous();` doesn't work together as you intend is due to their conflicting purposes. While using RequireAuthorization that enforces authorization checks, denying access to unauthorized users.
and AllowAnonymous explicitly allows access regardless of authorization status. However, when we are combining them creates ambiguity, leaving the behavior undefined.

So,  you could implement that in seperate endpoint as following:

```
var authorizedGroup = app.MapGroup("api/group2").WithTags("tag2").RequireAuthorization();


var anonymousGroup = app.MapGroup("api/group2").WithTags("tag2").AllowAnonymous();
```

If you notice, first endpoint Map endpoints that require authorization within authorizedGroup. On the other hand, another one endpoints that allow anonymous access within anonymousGroup.

By separating the mapping into distinct groups based on authorization requirements, you can ensure that the middleware is applied correctly to each set of endpoints. This should allow Swagger to handle both authorized and anonymous requests appropriately.

**Note:** Please also [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more insight.